# Java ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm having big troubles understanding the Java ThreadPoolExecutor. For example, I want to calculate the squares of numbers 1-1000:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    Callable<ArrayList<Integer>> c = new squareCalculator(1000);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    Future<ArrayList<Integer>> result = executor.submit(c);


    for(Integer i: result.get()){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

And the

```
public class squareCalculator implements Callable<ArrayList<Integer>>{
    private int i;
    private int max;

    private int threadID;
    private static int id;
    private ArrayList<Integer> squares;

    public squareCalculator(int max){
        this.max = max;
        this.i = 1;
        this.threadID = id;
        id++;
        squares = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> call() throws Exception {
        while(i <= max){            
            squares.add(i*i);
            System.out.println("Proccessed number " +i + " in thread "+this.threadID);
            Thread.sleep(1);
            i++;
        }
        return squares;

    }
}
```

Now my problem is, that I only get one thread doing the calculations. I expected to get 5 threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Callable` to run 5 times concurrently, you need to `submit` it 5 times.
You only submitted it once, and then ask for its result 5 times.

Javadoc of `submit()`:

> Submits **a** value-returning task for execution and returns a
>   Future representing the pending results of **the task**. The
>   Future's `get` method will return the task's result upon
>   successful completion.

You see that Javadoc for `submit()` uses the singular for "task", not "tasks".

The fix is easy: submit it multiple times:

```
Future<ArrayList<Integer>> result1 = executor.submit(c);
Future<ArrayList<Integer>> result2 = executor.submit(c);
Future<ArrayList<Integer>> result3 = executor.submit(c);
/// etc..

result1.get();
result2.get();
result3.get();
// etc..
```

Comment: Thank you, Erwin. Probably I misunderstand some very basic things. If I do it like that, the whole calculation of the square numbers of 1-1000 is done 3 times (concurrently), and I have 3 ArrayLists with the numbers 1, 4, 9, 16 etc. in the end. What I actually want is to split this whole calculation task among n-threads, to get one ArrayList but faster. But probably that cannot be done that easily?

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecutorService` will use one thread to execute each `Callable` task that you submit. Therefore, if you want to have multiple threads calculating the squares, you have to submit multiple tasks, for example one task for each number. You would then get a `Future<Integer>` from each task, which you can store in a list and call `get()` on each one to get the results.

```
public class SquareCalculator implements Callable<Integer> {
    private final int i;

    public SquareCalculator(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Processing number " + i + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return i * i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        // Create a Callable for each number, submit it to the ExecutorService and store the Future
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            Callable<Integer> c = new SquareCalculator(i);
            Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(c);
            futures.add(future);
        }

        // Wait for the result of each Future
        for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
            System.out.println(future.get());
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The output then looks something like this:

```
Processing number 2 in thread pool-1-thread-2
Processing number 1 in thread pool-1-thread-1
Processing number 6 in thread pool-1-thread-1
Processing number 7 in thread pool-1-thread-2
Processing number 8 in thread pool-1-thread-2
Processing number 9 in thread pool-1-thread-2
...
1
4
9
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny problem to try to do in parallel because creating the result array (or list) runs in O(n) time because it gets initialized with zeros on creation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int chunks = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    final int max = 1001;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(chunks);

    final List<ArrayList<Long>> results = new ArrayList<>(chunks);

    for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
        final int start = i * max / chunks;
        final int end = (i + 1) * max / chunks;
        final ArrayList<Long> localResults = new ArrayList<>(0);
        results.add(localResults);

        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Reallocate enough space locally so it's done in parallel.
                localResults.ensureCapacity(end - start);
                for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
                    localResults.add((long)j * (long)j);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

    int i = 0;
    for (List<Long> list : results) {
        for (Long l : list) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", i, l);
            ++i;
        }
    }

}
```

Overhead dealing with the wrapper classes will kill performance, here, so you should use something like Fastutil. Then, you could join them with something like Guava's Iterables.concat, only a List version that's compatible with Fastutil's LongList.

This might also make a good ForkJoinTask, but again, you'll need efficient logical (mapping, not copying; the reverse of List.sublist) List concatenation functions to realize a speedup.